# How to get the sum of column value using group in active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activeadmin

I have a Table called `Competiton` with the following columns

```
id contestant_id m1 m2 m3 total judge_id feedback
1        1       3   3  3   6       1        xxx
2        1       4   4  2   10      2        yyy
3        1       2   4  2   8       3        yzz
4        2       4   4  2   10      2        ss
5        3       2   4  2   8       3        yzccz
```

I want to get the sum of the total score of a contestant. For example
out could be like

```
contestant_id total 
      1         24 
      2         10
      3          8
```

I have tried the following ways

```
Competiton.group('contestant_id ').select("contestant_id , sum(total ) ")
```

I get errors as
`column "competiton.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Can someone help me with the active record query to achieve this? Thanks in advance.
PS: **I want to use the query in scoped_collection in Active admin**

Comment: Grouping by PK will not lead to any aggregation since the PK is unique by definition.

Comment: yes @mechnicov. I have tried.. in that case it gives multiple records for the same cotestant_id

Comment: Can you show the full code and SQL generated? Do you have a `order` clause somewhere or access to `id`?

Answer (score 0):

You could call `Competition.group(:contestant_id).sum(:total)`.

In your example, you should get the following result:

```
{3=>8, 2=>10, 1=>24}
```

The key is the `contestant_id`, and the value is the sum of `total`.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the suggestion.I have tried this way.. but since I have to use it in the active admin index page, the hash is not suitable.